# Javascript breaking on null value of property in Internet Explorer - How can I get IE to ignore this?

Tags: javascript, null, internet-explorer-9

Internet explorer is generating this error for the code that follows:

`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined`
`for "document.getElementById('files').files[0]`"

It's correct that ...files[0] is null, but I don't care, how can I tell IE not to care?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is not `document.getElementById('files').files` that is null? This would seem to be what the error implies.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Yea, I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks everyone for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('files'),
    file = elem.files && elem.files[0];
```

This will short-circuit and return `undefined` if files is undefined, otherwise it will return the first file.

Point of clarification, the error indicates that `files` is the undefined variable and accessing the property `0` is causing an error.  If it were `files[0]` itself, the expression would just return `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
var file;
if (document.getElementById('files').files){
    file = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
}
```

Comment: This will fail as `files` is the undefined object.  Checking the length will have the same problem as 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is very old but I want to answer for anyone who comes here like me

As Dennis says the error indicates that files is an undefined variable and I'm pretty sure that the problem is IE9 doesn't support files property.

As you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) IE10 is requiered for.

So try this:

```
var file; 
try{
   file = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
}catch(error){
   file= null;
}
```

PS:  I apologize for my poor English

Answer (score 0):

```
var file = document.getElementById('files').files[0] || "undefined";
```